# Is ice subject to the TSA's 3-1-1 Liquids Rule?

Tags: air-travel, usa, tsa

I was wondering if ice is subject to the liquids rule.

It is not a liquid, gel, aerosol, cream or paste.

Comment: At first thought, no. After all it is in solid state. You should remind that it is not forbidden to bring water to a plane. You can take an empty bottle an fill it after the security checkpoint, or buy one at the duty free.